# Loading & Deserialising Many JSON files into Specific C# Classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

I have a problem with C# and Unity3D. I would like to read in a series of some to many JSON files from a single directory, and deserialise the data into one specific class for each file.  I'm wondering if there's a fast way of looping that process so I don't need a large `if/switch` block or anything.  Deserialisation is fine, but I'm having trouble actually assigning the data from each file to a list containing objects of the correct `Type`.

Note: The class name is the same as the filename. For example, if the filename is *Cars.json*, I want to find a `Component` called `CarManager` and use it to store the deserialised data in a `List<Car>` at `CarManager.cars`.

I'm inexperienced, and I don't really know how to work with `Type` references yet.  If someone could explain how can I write the `ProcessFile()` method to successfully differentiate between `Object` types, so I can store the data for each file in Unity, I'd really appreciate it.

Cheers.

```
namespace Flight {

public class DatasetManager : MonoBehaviour {

private JsonSerializer serialiser;
private StreamReader streamReader;
private string path;
private string fileName;
private string extension;

public void Start() {
    // Define Path
    path = Application.dataPath + "/Data/";
    extension = "json";

    // Construct Serialiser     
    serialiser = new JsonSerializer();
    serialiser.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());       
    serialiser.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

    // Import Data
    Import();
}

private void Import() {
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*." + extension);
    if(files.Length == 0) return; 
    for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) ProcessFile(files[i]);
}

private void ProcessFile(string xFile) {

    streamReader = File.OpenText(xFile);

    // Read Filename
    string plural = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xFile);    
    string entity = plural.EndsWith("ies") ? plural.Substring(0,plural.Length-3) + "y" : plural.Substring(0,plural.Length-1);

    string manager = entity + "Manager";

    // Determine Entity & Manager Types
    System.Type entityType = System.Type.GetType("Flight." + entity);
    System.Type managerType = System.Type.GetType("Flight." + manager);
    if(entityType == null || managerType == null) return;

    // Determine List Type
    System.Type listType = null;
    listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
    if(listType == null) return;    

    // Acquire Data
    List<dynamic> data = System.Activator.CreateInstance(listType) as List<dynamic>;        
    data = serialiser.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(List<dynamic>)) as List<dynamic>;
    if(data == null) return;

    // Store Data in Game
    GameObject theGame = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Game");
    Component theComponent = theGame.GetComponent(manager);

    FieldInfo field = managerType.GetField(plural.ToLower());


    /*** How can I proceed from here? ***/


    List<dynamic> theList = field.GetValue(theComponent) as List<dynamic>;
    field.SetValue(theComponent, data);
}
}    
}
```

The above code produces an `ArgumentException`:

System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object] cannot be converted to target type: System.Collections.Generic.List1[Flight.Car]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries, fixed it. The following modified code within `ProcessFile()` appears to work properly:

```
private void ProcessFile(string xFile) {

        // ...
        // ...

        // Determine List Type
        System.Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
        if(listType == null) return;    

        // Acquire Data
        streamReader = File.OpenText(xFile);
        object data = null;
        data = System.Activator.CreateInstance(listType);        
        data = serialiser.Deserialize(streamReader, listType);
        if(data == null) return;

        // Store Data in Game
        GameObject theGame = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Game");
        Component theComponent = theGame.GetComponent(manager);

        FieldInfo field = managerType.GetField(plural.ToLower());
        field.SetValue(theComponent, data);
}
```